# How to save a document with a file mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, gridfs

I want to save a document(a person's information) in mongodb, with a pdf File uploaded and added in it(CV) which means each document is related with a file.
There is GridFS, i found that files are stored in two specific collections: files and chunk.

Is there any method to save document with reference file in it, or a way to map relationships between documents and stored files ?

Thank you.

Comment: Just have a mongo document field that contains a path on the file system or ec2.

Comment: but there isn't only one path, my web app handles a form where  profils enter information, and upload pdf file.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: You upload the PDF, save it to the file system, and save that path in the mongo document.

Comment: what i tried, is to save the file in the system, and the objectId of the file as a field in the document.

Comment: Mr Robert , the goal of my app is that a person upload the PDF from his/her computer and submit the form.When i try to download file, will it be downloaded with the path in his/ her system?

Comment: please check my answer in this post, problem solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530937/could-not-upload-file-using-mongodb-gridfs?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved this problem: i uploaded a MultipartFile, transfered it to a directory and then linked its objectId to a document, please check my answer in this link

[Could not Upload File using MongoDb GridFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530937/could-not-upload-file-using-mongodb-gridfs?noredirect=1)